# how to do quick replies on Facebook messenger bot using Wit.ai?

Tags: node.js, wit.ai, facebook-messenger-bot

I am trying to build Facebook Messenger bot using Node.Js and Wit.ai. The tutorial and the guides says about how to make a basic conversation bot. But, can someone tell me how to do Quick replies using Wit.ai on Facebook messenger bots?